# Quickstart for Java in the App Engine Flexible Environment - Cannot determine the default location of the Google Cloud SDK

Tags: bash, maven, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, gcloud

I've followed the quickstart guide, and have been stumped at [deploying](https://cloud.google.com/java/getting-started/hello-world#deploy_and_run_hello_world_on_app_engine) for a few hours. When I run mvn gcloud:deploy command, I get the following error.

> INFO] Running gcloud app deploy...
>   [ERROR] Cannot determine the default location of the Google Cloud SDK.
>   [ERROR] If you need to install the Google Cloud SDK, follow the instructions located at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/managed-vms
>   [ERROR] You can then set it via   in the pom.xml

Which results in a Build Failure. I have checked my environment variables, and the current paths, which were generated by the install, are set as the following in my .bash_profile

> #The next line updates PATH for the Google Cloud SDK.
>   source '/Users/user/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc'
>
> #The next line enables shell command completion for gcloud.
>   source'/Users/user/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc'

I tried to manually set the path by getting path through a quick which gcloud and added it to my PATH variable, however this did not change anything either. I tried to follow the instructions given by the error message and referred to the following link to correct this issue.

> https//github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-maven-plugin/issues/8

(I can't post another link due to lack of reputation, so add a ":" after the "https" to go to the link)

it still wont build. Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!